# Find the largest number from NSArray that is smaller than the given number

Tags: objective-c, sorting, search, nsarray

Suppose I have a sorted array of integers int[], and I want to search the closest smaller value to some input number.

for example if the array contains `1`, `23`, `57`, `59`, `120` and the input is `109`, the output should be `59`.
I have tried this but it is not working out as needed.

```
NSTimeInterval currentTime = self.player.currentTime;
NSInteger playerTime=currentTime;
NSUInteger index = [_timesArray indexOfObject:@(playerTime)
                                inSortedRange:NSMakeRange(0, _timesArray.count-1)
                                      options:NSBinarySearchingFirstEqual | NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex
                              usingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
                                  return [a compare:b];
                              }];
```

Comment: you have sorted array and what you need is to step downward from biggest number to smallest... algorithm is simple here!

Answer (score 2):

Your code does work as expected with the example data you gave:

```
NSArray *_timesArray = @[@1, @23, @57, @59, @120];
NSTimeInterval currentTime = 109;
NSInteger playerTime=currentTime;
NSUInteger index = [_timesArray indexOfObject:@(playerTime)
                                inSortedRange:NSMakeRange(0, _timesArray.count-1)
                                      options:NSBinarySearchingFirstEqual | NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex
                              usingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
                                  return [a compare:b];
                              }];
NSLog(@"Index: %lu", (unsigned long)index);
```

Output:

```
Index: 4
```

Check your inputs.  Likely they are not what you think they are.

Comment: Index equal 4 means 120 value.

Comment: No, index of 4 does not mean 120.  The output of indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator: is the index at which the object should be inserted.  "If the NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex option is specified, returns the index at which you should insert obj in order to maintain a sorted array."  See the Apple docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:

Answer (score 1):

As I said before: "you have sorted array and what you need is to step downward from biggest number to smallest... algorithm is simple here!"

```
    NSNumber* givenNumber = @(105);
    for (NSNumber* item in [@[@(1), @(23), @(57), @(59), @(120)] reverseObjectEnumerator]){
        // go downward
        if (item.integerValue < givenNumber.integerValue)
        {
            NSLog(@"%@ < %@",item,givenNumber);
            // save this number somewhere
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is just a slower re-implementation of the searching done by indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:.  The issue is not that the method provided by Apple does not search correctly...

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved by binary_search_like algorithm which runs in O(lg n) , but I don't know objective-c so I'll give code in c++.

I assume the given element is not in the array.

```
int binary_search_like(int s[], int key, int low, int high)
{
    int middle; 
    if (low > high) return (s[high]); 

    middle = (low + high) / 2;

    if (s[middle] > key)
        return(binary_search_like(s, key, low, middle - 1));
    else
        return(binary_search_like(s, key, middle + 1, high));
}

int Search(int s[], int key, int size){

    if (key > s[size - 1]) return s[size - 1];
    // Check if key < smallest element , give error !

    return binary_search_like(s, key, 0, size);

 }
```

Comment: The example code given in the question (indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:) is already performing a binary search.  No need to write your own in C++.