# Compare integer value with NSMutableArray and find maximum of that value

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

Suppose I have a integer number 10. and my NSMutableArray contains 1 to 20 values. So I have to find maximum of 10 from NSMutableArray means the answer is 11.

I know how to find maximum number.

```
int max = [[numbers valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"] intValue];
```

But I don't know how to compare and find maximum number from array. I can use for loop to find but is there any faster solution like above?

Comment: Refer it hope it will help you.. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238072/find-the-largest-number-from-nsarray-that-is-smaller-than-the-given-number

Comment: Means you want to find maximum number right after 10 from array???

Comment: Thanks @PrashantTukadiya.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSArray *_timesArray = @[@1, @23, @57, @59, @120];
NSTimeInterval currentTime = 109;
NSInteger playerTime=currentTime;
NSUInteger index = [_timesArray indexOfObject:@(playerTime)
                                inSortedRange:NSMakeRange(0, _timesArray.count-1)
                                      options:NSBinarySearchingFirstEqual | NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex
                              usingComparator:^(id a, id b) {
                                  return [a compare:b];
                              }];
NSLog(@"Index: %lu", (unsigned long)index);
```

your answer is 4;

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your array like this.

```
NSMutableArray *numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10",@"11",@"12",@"13",@"14",@"15",@"16",@"17",@"18",@"19",@"20", nil];
```

And declare your number like this.

```
int max = 11;
int find;
```

Here max is the your static declaration. And find is the your result maximum number.

```
for(int i = 0;i<numbers.count;i++)
{
     if(max < [[numbers objectAtIndex:i]intValue])
     {
         find = [[numbers objectAtIndex:i]intValue];
         NSLog(@"%d",find);
         break;
     }
}
```

Do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSMutableArray *numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"20", @"1", @"2", @"3", @"4", @"5", @"6", @"7", @"8", @"9", @"10", @"11", @"12", @"13", @"14", @"15", @"16", @"17", @"18", @"19", @"20", nil];
    int minimum = 10;
    int nextNumber = [[numbers valueForKeyPath:@"@max.intValue"] intValue];

    for(int i = 0;i<numbers.count;i++)
    {
        if([[numbers objectAtIndex:i] intValue] > minimum) {
            if([[numbers objectAtIndex:i] intValue] < nextNumber) {
                nextNumber = [[numbers objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
            }
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Maxmimum number right after %d from whole array is: %d",minimum, nextNumber);
```